# How to filter Previous Page Paths with specific hostname in Google Analytics/Data Studio

Tags: google-analytics, looker-studio

I've generated a simple chart in Data Studio to show where people went next from our homepage. This is easy using Page as a dimension and filtering:

Previous Page Path = /

But now I realise that '/' includes other homepages for a range of subdomains on our site.

I can't filter them all out, because I need to know if people went there next from the main www homepage. I just want to filter the previous hostnames out where they aren't www.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just [create a filter](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6291066?hl=en) with the [`ga:hostname`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=page_tracking&jump=ga_hostname) dimension (probably just called `hostname` in the Data Studio UI).

Comment: I can't filter them all out, because I need to know if people went to a different hostname page from the main www homepage. I just want to filter the _previous_ hostnames out where they aren't www.